# Determine checksum / CRC algorithm

Tags: protocol, crc, networking, packet

I am doing reverse engineering on some network protocol. It is client to server communication and I am pretty stuck with identifying checksum (or CRC) algorithm used in packet structure.

I tried reveng util but without any result (so maybe it is not CRC). Also I lookout on standard CRCs algorithm online but nothing fits my samples.

Here are some examples of packets:

client to server:

```
66  01 00 01 fa 00 00 00  b7 33  00 00 fc 00 00 00  99 
66  01 00 03 fa 00 00 00  c7 d9  00 00 fd 00 00 00  99
66  01 00 03 fa 00 00 80  d1 c2  08  99
66  01 00 03 fa 00 00 71  46 42  00 00 05 00 00 00 ab 55 52 5c 5b 50 51 55 55 55 54 73  99
66  01 00 03 fa 00 00 04  45 a2  00 00 6b 00 00 00 ab 55 40 5c 49 3e 47 1d 55 b4 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 45 bb  99
```

server to client:

```
66  01 fa 00 00 01 00 00  91 57  0a  99
66  01 fa 00 00 03 00 00  8a bb  0a  99
66  01 fa 00 00 01 00 96  9d 37  00 00 00 00 00 00 ab 55 55 55 ab  99
66  01 fa 00 00 03 00 7f  61 68  00 00 44 00 00 00 ab 55 51 54 56 11 54 55 1e  99 
66  01 fa 00 00 03 00 7a  70 dd  08 99
```

I think checksum is 16-bit number begin on 9th byte. Also, I believe that the first and last bytes are not significant to count the checksum algorithm (start and stop constat).

I can provide more samples if it helps.

I will be grateful for any help or advice from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure it out by myself.

All bytes, including start and stop byte, must be passed to CRC algorithm. Important part is CRC bytes must be substituted with zero.

For example

```
66 01 fa 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 0a 99
```

get result **0x9157** in standard **CRC-16/TELEDISK** algorithm.

I found very useful this online CRC calculator: https://crccalc.com/